# Correct method to prevent null byte injection with HTML/Javascript/PHP text box

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, passwords

I'm  currently creating a Javascript/HTML/PHP sign up form for a web app. I want to make it as secure as possible, and was reading up on null-byte injection into PHP. Am I correct in thinking that in order to prevent such a thing, I need to not allow special characters (null-byte characters) like %&£#@?! etc, from being chosen as a password when users are signing up?

Users type their username and password into two HTML text boxes, I have the username checking my database (with a php script) with an onBlur event of the username text box, that checks to see if the username is already used in the database, and if it is then it disables the "Sign Up" button and alerts the user to the issue.

I want to do something similar with the password text box. If the user enters a password with a special character (eg, "mypassword!") then I want to disable the "Sign Up" button and inform them that passwords must only contain letters and numbers.

Is this the correct way to prevent null-byte injection? Or is it equally secure to allow special characters in passwords with some sort of check inside the PHP file?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: so you want to DELIBERATELY weaken passwords, making it EASIER to guess/hack them later? You should be encouraging passwords that are as UGLY and COMPLICATED as possible.

Comment: `Is this the correct way to prevent null-byte injection?` no - _any_ client side code is implicitly not in your control. The user can trivially bypass it - say, by disabling JS in their browser. You should never, _ever_ rely on client-side validation only - you can have it, but it will ONLY serve to improve user experience, not to protect your server.

Comment: the best and only right way to prevent null-byte-injection in passwords is doing what is the basic best practice, anyway.. using `password_hash()`

Comment: oh, and what [search engine of my choice] [spat out](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/null-byte-injection-php/) `$input = str_replace(chr(0), '', $input);`

Comment: Hi @FranzGleichmann thanks for your reply. I'm already using password_hash() before inputting the username and passwords into my database (and using password_verify when logging the user in). But the reason I asked this question was due to a comment on the hash php manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php there's a comment from a user named "Lyo Mi" that mentions the hash function truncating passwords with null-byte characters. If that's true then I can't think of another way to prevent null characters than on the client-side.  Is that comment incorrect?

Comment: Hi @MarcB thanks for your comment, please see my above reply to Franz, could you take a look at the link/comment I mention as I would like your advice on it too. Thanks again.

Comment: @Emily you can *not* prevent the input of anything on the client side. *every* validation *must* happen on the server side. also: no regular user would ever send a password with a null-byte, and there is nothing to gain for an attacker in feeding a null-byte into password_hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as CW since it's not an answer. @emily: either they fixed it (testing on PHP7), or the comment's wrong:

```
php > echo password_hash("123\0456", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$2y$10$UQ7o/1ggpeqQYQaAPDQUxeAq0vPFJCenBJEzDFkcFXirrz6HC7N9.
php > var_dump( password_verify("123\0456", '$2y$10$UQ7o/1ggpeqQYQaAPDQUxeAq0vPFJCenBJEzDFkcFXirrz6HC7N9.'));
bool(true)
php > var_dump( password_verify("123", '$2y$10$UQ7o/1ggpeqQYQaAPDQUxeAq0vPFJCenBJEzDFkcFXirrz6HC7N9.'));
bool(false)
```

Comment: Hi again, that's great, my server is 7.0.12, so that means I don't need to worry about users using special characters? Thanks again.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your test. `\045` is not a NUL byte.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the above post by Marc B, don't you still need to be careful? Look at what happens here if we use \000 as the NULL byte signal (PHP v7).

```
php > echo password_hash("123\000456", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$2y$10$GNQS2Wxj.L/5WukaOJEcxeOwgIgzug5BvCVvyVJOAUTkpfW2HiclO
php > var_dump( password_verify("123\000456", '$2y$10$GNQS2Wxj.L/5WukaOJEcxeOwgIgzug5BvCVvyVJOAUTkpfW2HiclO'));
bool(true)
php > var_dump( password_verify("123", '$2y$10$GNQS2Wxj.L/5WukaOJEcxeOwgIgzug5BvCVvyVJOAUTkpfW2HiclO'));
bool(true)
php > var_dump( password_verify("123\000NothingMattersPastTheNull!", '$2y$10$GNQS2Wxj.L/5WukaOJEcxeOwgIgzug5BvCVvyVJOAUTkpfW2HiclO'));
bool(true)
```

Personally, when using password_hash()/bcrypt I sanitize passwords to contain upper and lowercase alpha, all numbers with the addition of .!$^&*()[]@-_+, and to a maximum of 72 chars. This is perfectly fine for my application, which is not the storage of nuclear missile codes. If you're asking the internet for answers, then you are probably not working on the storage of life endangering information, so the above sanitization will probably work for you as well and you can disregard the doom-mongers telling you that you're risking life and limb by throwing around sayings like 'you're reducing entropy!'.

I'd happily make a password, between 8 and 72 chars long using my defined character set and provide the password_hash() to a 'brute the password' contest, safe in the knowledge it will take some serious high end hardware and a LOT of time to find the collision. Mix the above into good system security, transferring all information over TLS and preventing other common problems like injection attacks with prepared statements/etc, and you're well on the way to having enough security in place to stop all but the most determined, state sponsored activity.